# Hosting ASP.NET Application on LAN Network

Tags: asp.net

We have hosted Asp.Net application on local computer in LAN network. This application is accessible by other LAN computer via ip address.

However If I am trying to bind the site with host name for example ( mysite.com ), the other computers in LAN, they are getting unkown host error.

Would anybody please help me in this regard ? how to make other system in LAN to access this application via host name instead of IP address. ?

Thanks 
PK

Comment: By setting up a DNS entry for it, and having your computers read from that entry?

Comment: @pravin you can Connect to the server via its LAN host-name (computer name), using that host-name in the URL:`http://computer-name/` .For this to work, the LAN host-name must be assigned as one of the website’s Domain Aliases, and all redirects from Aliases to the Primary Domain Name must be turned off.

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to run your [own DHCP and DNS server on your local network.](https://superuser.com/questions/45789/running-dns-locally-for-home-network)

Alternative a quick and dirty solution is to modify the `host` file on (all) your local network computers (are less than 20 ?) and add there your site name in a line eg:

> 192.168.1.140 www.localsite.com

The `host` file is located at `c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`